# How to compare two mysql table structure in file using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql dump files.

**dump1.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE `designs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `template` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**dump2.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE `designs` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `act` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      `temp` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

How to find the difference in two table structure in dump1 & dump2?

Answer (score 1):

Second query select all COLUMN_NAME of table1 and by using NOT IN we compare COLUMN of both table  :-

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' AND 
      TABLE_NAME = 'table2' AND 
      COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
         SELECT COLUMN_NAME
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' AND 
               TABLE_NAME = 'table1');
```

Comment: I would like to compare the two sql dump files.

Comment: before create table plz change table names and use this query

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'designs1' AND 
      COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
         SELECT COLUMN_NAME
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
         WHERE  
               TABLE_NAME = 'designs2')

Comment: Actullay, I want to restore the database from dump.sql file. The table `designs` related functionality already done.

Comment: I have maintained the dump1.sql file in server. while restoring the dump2.sql file, i want to check the table structure is correct or not? ie) table structure is identical to the dump1.sql

Comment: first create 2 new tables and than upload your both dump file and use my MySQL query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93449/discussion-between-rahautos-and-vinoth).

Comment: Please don't just post "code only" answers. While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations! [**And it's not just this one!**](http://pastebin.com/9GE2A5rr)

Comment: Also you then [improve your answer in so many ways and many more!](http://pastebin.com/9v6KFiM8)

Comment: Use the [help] to improve your answers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer , http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: To get ideas how good answers can be formatted, structured or worded. Just look at some good ones: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108/3933332 and see the options you have with formatting, additional information, explanations and references.

Answer (score 0):

But your table names should be different to check this.
try this,

```
select column_name
      ,max(case when table_name = 'table_1' then 'Yes' end) as in_table_1
      ,max(case when table_name = 'table_2' then 'Yes' end) as in_table_2
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_name in('table_1', 'table_2')
   and table_schema = 'your_database'
  group
    by column_name
 order
    by column_name;
```

Or, if you want to use files,

```
mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -u root -p dbName1>file1.sql
mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -u root -p dbName2>file2.sql

diff file1.sql file2.sql
```

For more information, see [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75532/query-to-compare-the-structure-of-two-tables-in-mysql) All possible ways are given here.

Comment: I have to verify the dump file without importing, any suggestions.

Comment: Did u checked that link??

Comment: Actullay, I want to restore the database from dump.sql file. The table designs related functionality already done.

Comment: I have maintained the dump1.sql file in server. while restoring the dump2.sql file, i want to check the table structure is correct or not? ie) table structure is identical to the dump1.sql